# How does ASP.NET MVC repopulate values in form when validation fails?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, web-applications

In web forms the view state is used. But in ASP.NET MVC since model binding is available the properties can be easily acccessed in the controller. However when the model validation fails, does the ASP.NET MVC automatically populate the form controls realising that the validation has failed?

Or is there any other way by which this is accomplished.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is an property called `ModelState` (in `Controller` class), that holds all the values. It is used in model binding. When validation fails, `ModelState` holds all the values with validation errors.

`ModelState.IsValid` tells you, that validation didn't throw any errors.

`ModelState.Values` holds all the values and errors.

**EDIT**

Example for Ufuk:

View model:

```
public class EmployeeVM
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

Actions:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult CreateEmployee()
{
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CreateEmployee(EmployeeVM model)
{
    model.FirstName = "AAAAAA";
    model.LastName = "BBBBBB";
    return View(model);
}
```

View:

```
@model MvcApplication1.Models.EmployeeVM

@using (Html.BeginForm("CreateEmployee", "Home")) {
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m)
    <input type="submit" value="Save"/>
}
```

As you can see, in POST method values are overwritten with AAAAA and BBBBB, but after POST, form still displays posted values. They are taken from `ModelState`.

Comment: Does that mean when the validation fails automatically the values from the modelstate.values are populated on to the form?

Comment: @LukLed : Are u missing `Required Fields` in View Model ?

Comment: @PankajGarg: This example was about `ModelState`, not required fields.

Comment: @@LukLed : I was curious to know, Domain Model should contains Required Fields. Same is true for `View Models` ?

Comment: @PankajGarg: It is common pattern to decorate view model with data annotations used to validate this model, so using `Required`, `StringLength` or `Email` attributes is completely normal thing to do.

Comment: @LukLed - Let's say the Domain Model contains `First Name` or `Last Name` or `Date of Birth`. and View Model should have `Full Name` or `Age`. In this example, we are describing the `View Models` in `De-Normalized` way. So why `Data-Annotations` are required in `View Model` ?

Comment: @PankajGarg: View models used to present data on page don't need these attributes, so there is no need to add `Required` to `FullName`, but if values are posted back, they need to be validated, so data annotations are useful. Specially useful when you want to use client side validation.

Comment: @LukLed : Then why don't we use Domain Model directly for validation? As you suggested that in both case (`Domain Model and View Model`) need Data Annotations. Why are we creating De-Normalized classes ? Then it becomes necessary to use `Auto-Mappers` for `View-Models`.

Comment: @PankajGarg - It's not *necessary*, it's simply best practice.  Often your view has different validation requirements than your domain model, if that's the case then you can't pass your domain model directly (otherwise your validation will be incorrect).  As an example, when you have a multi-step "wizard" where you are only filling in some fields of the model on any given step.  Another reason is for security.  Although there are ways to prevent unwanted binding, it's a hassle and easier to use a view model that only contains the data you need in the view.

Comment: @PankajGarg - In general, View Models represent the concept of "least access", that is, you only pass the data that's required to the view, not an entire model that contains things you don't need.  If you're only doing simple CRUD operations where everything matches up, and you have no sensitive information in the model, then sure.. go ahead, pass the domain model.  However, most apps have more complex requirements.

Comment: @MystereMan - Thanks for the clarification and +1 to your both comments